# c# richtextbox only shows one line

Tags: c#, parsing, richtextbox

been searching the internet for some time now and cant find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to parse some lines into the richtextbox, but i only get one line instead of all of them. Heres a part of my code

```
        foreach (var val in lineCountDict)
        {
            richTextBox2.Text = (val.Key + " - " + val.Value + " Drops -" +
            ((double)val.Value / (double)mobDeathCounter) * 100 + " % chance\n");


        }
```

So when i run this i only get one line, any advice would be awesome

Thank you!

Comment: that's because you are overwriting each time though the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you get one line since in each iteration you set `richTextBox2.Text` to the new value which replaces the old value.

Use `richTextBox2.Text+="..."`